# How would you implement a toString method, on the base class, if the string class inherits from the base class?

Tags: oop, inheritance, language-agnostic, programming-languages

In many modern `OOP` languages, such as `Java` and `C#`, reference types have a base class typically called `Object` from which all other reference types inherit their core functionality.

These languages also have a universal `.toString()` method shared across all the reference types, so that it's easy to extract data as a string from it.

Now here's the question: If the `String` class is a subclass of `Object`, how can `Object` implement a `.toString()` method without causing a circular dependency?

if `A` uses `B` and `B` implements `A` it's bound to cause problems, or am I totally wrong in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding C# (and I'm pretty sure the same goes for Java), the compiler doesn't require that source files be provided in *dependency order*.

This means that, unlike other compilers (the F# compiler and gcc, I believe), the C# compiler allows you to refer to symbols that haven't been seen by the compiler yet (as long as both types are in the same assembly).

In other words - yes, there's is a circular dependency, but the compiler takes care of that for you. If you want to know how compilers handle circular dependencies, then that has been asked on [`programmers.stackexchange`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/158180/compiler-linking-how-to-handle-circular-references) already.